# Set post_status to 'trash' does not work in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I try to execute the following SQL statement in phpMyAdmin to set some posts to trash:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET wp_posts.post_status = 'trash'
WHERE (wp_posts.post_title REGEXP '^DataNumen Outlook Repair [0-9\.]+ is released on [0-9a-zA-Z\s\,]+')
AND (wp_posts.post_type = 'post') 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
```

After the executing, it shows 5 records are updated.

However, in WP dashboard, I check and found those deleted by MySQL statement is a bit different from those manually deleted, as below:

[image]

They are still show status as published and has "Trash" & "View" options.

I try to set some more posts to trash via MySQL statement, this time, they do not show in "Trash" tab at all, but the Trash count increase.

So is there something wrong to trash posts via MySQL statement?

Comment: It usually is wrong to do almost anything directly in DB in Wordpress due to inner mechanics you don't see, use hooks: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_trash_post/

Comment: When deleting via the UI it inserts into `postmeta` with `meta_key` `_wp_trash_meta_status` and `_wp_trash_meta_time`, and quite possibly others. It also updates statistics on taxonomies.